# Fetch form variables in node

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

After making a request to URL I get a HTML page as a response.THe responded page consists of a form of whose variable I want to fetch.

**Output**

```
<input type="hidden" name="Flag_CustomerStatus" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="Flag_InstantPayment" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="txtMerchNum" value="90">
<input type="hidden" name="txtHttp" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/ThankYouPage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="txtMerchRequest" value="add_cc">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="IsPostBack" value="True">
<input type="hidden" name="Lng" value="en">
```

I am familiar with Php and I can extract these variables using `$_POST['Flag_CustomerStatus']` but I am not able to parse them when implemmenting in Node Js.

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

after you get success ajax result - you can write this html to other div
like this

```
<div style='display:none;' id='hidden_div'>
....
....
$('#hidden_div').html(your_html);
```

after it you can choice any value by JQuery from any hidden input

Or second solution is - you can change php side
and get array with values, after it - you can generate HTML